# How to take numbers if the stdin is of this form: [2,7,11,15] in python and java

Tags: java, python

How to take numbers if the stdin is of this form: `[2,7,11,15]`

```
l = list(map(int, input().split(','))) ; print(l)
```

input : `[2,7,11,15]`

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[2'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 3):

If you split using only the comma, you keep the `[` and `]`

```
value.split(',') >> ['[2', '7', '11', '15]']
```

You can do one of these ways :

- manually    `l = list(map(int, value[1:-1].split(',')))`
- using a lib `l = ast.literal_eval(value)` (`import ast`)

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, rather use `ast.literal_eval` or some kind of an own parser. But for the sake of your simple example, you could go for:

```
somestring = "[2,7,11,15]"

somelist = list(map(int, map(str.strip, somestring.strip("[]").split(","))))
print(somelist)
# [2, 7, 11, 15]
```